# Filling na values with unique values for each na in a column in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, na

I want to fill each na value with a unique value like auto increasing 1,2,3...42 if there are 42 na values in a column.

These values can be anything as long as they are unique.

I tried using a list in fillna method but it didn't accept a list

`df\['column_name'\].fillna(\[values in list for each na\]`

```
  A  B  C
0 na na 1
1 a  R  2  
2 b  T  na
3 na na na
```

should become:-

```
  A     B     C
0 na_1  na_1  1
1 a     R     2
2 b     T     na_1
3 na_2  na_2  na_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need replace by consecutive numbers `1,2,3..` use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
#if necessary
df = df.replace('na', np.nan)

m = df.isna()
df1 = df.mask(m, m.cumsum())
print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  a  R  2
2  b  T  1
3  2  2  2
```

If need replace by list add [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by dictionary from `enumerate`:

```
L = [f'na_{x}' for x in range(1, 43)]

d = dict(enumerate(L, 1))
# print (d)

m = df.isna()
df2 = df.mask(m, m.cumsum().replace(d))
print (df2)
      A     B     C
0  na_1  na_1     1
1     a     R     2
2     b     T  na_1
3  na_2  na_2  na_2
```